# Mongoose upsert subarray of a doc already found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I already queried & found a doc for some other reasons.

```
device.find({name})
.then(devices => {
let dev1 = devices[0];

//some code that I use dev1 and made a output that I want to upsert

//upsert here

});
```

How i can upsert in a subarray of dev1 without any additionally queries(such as findOneAndUpdate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved by doing this,

```
dev1.subarray.push(data);
```